# Help with mysql sum and group query and managing results for jquery graph

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a system I am trying to design that will retrieve information from a database, so that it can be plotted in a jquery graph. I need to retrieve the information and somehow put it in the necessary coordinates format (for example two coordinates `var d = [[1269417600000, 10],[1269504000000, 15]];`).

My table that I am selecting from is a table that stores user votes with fields:

```
points_id (1=vote up, 2=vote down),
user_id,
timestamp, (UNIX TIMESTAMP)
topic_id
```

What I need to do is select all the votes and somehow group them into respective days and then sum the difference between 1 votes and 2 votes for each day. I then need to somehow display the data in the appropriate plotting format shown earlier. For example April 1, 4 votes.  The data needs to be separated by commas, except the last plot entry, so I am not sure how to approach that. I showed an example below of the kind of thing I need but it is not correct,

```
echo "var d=[";
$query=mysql_query(
    "SELECT *, SUM(IF(points_id = \"1\", 1,0))-SUM(IF([points_id = \"2\", 1,0)) AS 'total'
    FROM points LEFT JOIN topic ON topic.topic_id=points.topic_id
    WHERE topic.creator='$user' GROUP by timestamp
    HAVING certain time interval"
);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $timestamp=$row['timestamp'];
    $votes=$row['total'];
    echo "[$timestamp,$vote],";
}
echo "];";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would certainly be a lot saner to just use -1 as a downvote. Then you can simply run `SUM(points_id)`

To generate javascript-friendly notation, you can use good old mate `json_encode`.

```
$sql = "SELECT `timestamp`, SUM(points_id) FROM ..."; // yadda yadda
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$out = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $out[] = array((int) $row['timestamp'], (int) $row['total']);
}
echo "d = " . json_encode($out) . ";\n";
```

Comment: +1. Using negative values for downvotes would indeed be a lot saner.

Comment: thanks nickf these are all good points lol. I just have one question, is it possible to group and add together votes by intervals of days. For example april 1: 22, april 2: 80 etc. I know stackoverflow does this so it is possible but I am just not sure the best way to approach it or if it can even be done in one query. And as for javascript notation, I want all the entries to have commas except the last one, how should this be done?

Comment: PS I am not insane, just a noob.

Comment: k I tried to post an answer but I am havin technical difficulties. This query worked

$query=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(IF(points_id = \"1\", 1,0))-SUM(IF(points_id = \"2\", 1,0)) AS 'total',FROM_UNIXTIME(points.timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d') as one FROM points LEFT JOIN topic on topic.topic_id=points.topic_id WHERE topic.creator='gg' GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(point.timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d')");

your json approach works, thanks nickf

Comment: You can do something like `GROUP BY DAYOFYEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp))`